# Asp.Net AutoEventWireup - what is it doing code wise

Tags: asp.net, autoeventwireup

I've been digging thru the Page, TemplateControl and Control classes in reflector trying to figure out where AutoEventWireUp property is actually getting used. I've failed miserably.

My understanding of AutoEventWireUp is sketchy but I think it casues event handler methods to be automatically wired up to events? 
So I thought I'd see some code where this is happening, but this isn't the case.

Where is AutoEventWireUp actually used under the hood? Can I see the code in reflector?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to write up an explanation but K. Scott Allen [has a much better one](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/16/2914.aspx).

My advice is to avoid `AutoEventWireup` and either override base "OnEvent" methods or explicitly wire up your own events as this will be faster, less magical, and easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for that, for some reason my googling didn't find that one.